# background: url("/img/mobile/star_18.svg") not working in stock (android default browser)

Tags: css

background: url("/img/mobile/star_18.svg") not working in stock (android default browser).

Problem is coming in Stock browser of android version 4.3 and lower. It is working fine in chrome or firefox in android version 4.3 and lower.

Comment: Add width and height attributes for svg tag and it will be work.

Comment: Try to change the image type from svg to png or jpg etc.. not sure but just suggestions most browsers are not sporting svg